# Tengo estas 2 advertencias que no se cómo corregir y mi programa no funciona bien. C++

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo programando, intenté hacer este programa y funciona bien hasta que selecciono un caso de dos dígitos, ¿Saben qué está pasando?¿Cómo podría hacer que funcione? Ya comprobé que es tema de los dos dígitos porque otro programa donde solo están del 1 al 9 funciona perfecto.Y las advertencias las pone en los case de dos dígitos. 
Un ejemplo de cada advertencia:

> 134    9   C:\Users\Documents\C++\Calculadora.cpp  [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
>
> 134    9   C:\Users\Documents\C++\Calculadora.cpp  [Warning] case label value exceeds maximum value for type

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
char opcion;
float num1,num2,num3,num4,perimetro,area,resultado;
float pi = atan(1)*4; 

int main (){
    do{
        std::cout<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------";
        std::cout<<"\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>Calculadora Suprema<<<<<<<<<<<<<";
        std::cout<<"\n  1.-Suma";
        std::cout<<"\n  2.-Resta";
        std::cout<<"\n  3.-Multiplicacion";
        std::cout<<"\n  4.-Division";
        std::cout<<"\n  5.-Area de un cuadrado";
        std::cout<<"\n  6.-Area de un triangulo";
        std::cout<<"\n  7.-Area de un circulo";
        std::cout<<"\n  8.-Area de un poligono regular";
        std::cout<<"\n  9.-Volumen de un prisma rectangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  10.-Volumen de un prisma triangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  11.-Volumen de un prisma poligonal";
        std::cout<<"\n  12.-Volumen de un cilindro";
        std::cout<<"\n  13.-Volumen de un cilindro truncado diagonal";
        std::cout<<"\n  14.-Volumen de una esfera";
        std::cout<<"\n  15.-Volumen de el segmento de una esfera";
        std::cout<<"\n  16.-Volumen de el casquete de una esfera";
        std::cout<<"\n  17.-Volumen de una piramide rectangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  18.-Volumen de una piramide triangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  19.-Volumen de una piramide poligonal";
        std::cout<<"\n  20.-Volumen de un cono";
        std::cout<<"\n  21.-Volumen de un cono truncado";
        std::cout<<"\n  22.-Salir";
        do{
            std::cout<<"\n Intruduzca su opcion (1-22):";
            fflush(stdin);
            std::cin>>opcion;
        } while(opcion < '1' || opcion > '22');
        switch(opcion){
            case '1':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una suma";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu primer sumando: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu segundo sumando: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=num1+num2;
                std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la suma es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '2':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una resta";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu minuendo: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu sustraendo: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=num1-num2;
                std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la resta es: "<<resultado;
                break;  

            case '3':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una multiplicacion";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu primer operando: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu segundo operando: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=num1*num2;
                std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la multiplicacion es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '4':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una division";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu dividendo: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu divisor: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=num1/num2;
                std::cout<<"\n El resultado de la division es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '5':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un cuadrado";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la base: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Indroduce la altura: 2";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=num1*num1;
                std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '6':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un triangulo";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la base: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Indroduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=(num1*num2)/2;
                std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '7':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un circulo";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                resultado=pi*(num1*num1);
                std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '8':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un poligono";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la cantidad de lados: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la medida de cada lado: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                perimetro=num1*num2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el apotema: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                resultado=(perimetro*num3)/2;
                std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '9':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un prisma rectangular";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de largo: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                area=num1*num2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                resultado=num3*area;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '10':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un prisma triangular";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la base: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                area=(num1*num2)/2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura del prisma: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                resultado=num3*area;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '11':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un prisma poligonal";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la cantidad de lados: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide cada lado: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                perimetro=num1*num2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la apotema: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                area=(perimetro*num3)/2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num4;
                resultado=area*num4;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '12':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cilindro";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                area=pi*(num1*num1);
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=area*num2;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
                break;

            case '13':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cilindro diagonal";
                std::cout<<"\n Ingrese la altura mayor: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Ingresa la altura menor: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                std::cout<<" Ingresa el radio: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                num4=(num1+num2)/2;
                resultado=pi*(num3*num3)*num4;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '14':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una esfera";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                resultado=(4*pi*(num1*num1*num1))/3;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
                break;

            case '15':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen del segmento de una esfera";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio mayor: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio menor: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                resultado=(pi*num3*((3*(num1*num1))+(3*(num2*num2))+(num3*num3)))/6;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
                break;

            case '16':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen del casquete de una esfera";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                resultado=(pi*(num2*num2)*((3*num1)-num2))/3;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
                break;

            case '17':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una piramide rectangular";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de largo: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                area=num1*num2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la pirámide. ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                resultado=(num3*area)/3;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '18':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una piramide triangular";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la base: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                area=(num1*num2)/2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la pirámide. ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                resultado=(num3*area)/3;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '19':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una piramide poligonal";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la cantidad de lados: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide cada lado: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                perimetro=num1*num2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la apotema: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                area=(perimetro*num3)/2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num4;
                resultado=(area*num4)/3;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '20':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cono";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                num3=pi*(num1*num1);
                resultado=(num3*num2)/3;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

            case '21':
                std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cono truncado";
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
                std::cin>>num1;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio mayor: ";
                std::cin>>num2;
                std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio menor: ";
                std::cin>>num3;
                resultado=pi*num1*((num2*num2)+(num3+num3)+num2+num3)/3;
                std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
                break;

        }
    } while (opcion != '22');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 134 9 C:\Users\Documents\C++\Calculadora.cpp [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

En C++ (y C) las comillas simples denotan un literal para un solo carácter (tipo `char` en C++ / `int` en C). Las comillas dobles en cambio denotan un literal de cadena.

El problema es:

```
case '10':
     ^^^^
```

el compilador se queja porque estás usando comillas simples que denotan un literal para `char` para acotar una cadena de caracteres.

> 134 9 C:\Users\Documents\C++\Calculadora.cpp [Warning] case label value exceeds maximum value for type

El problema es la misma línea (y los demás case que le siguen) que antes.

`char` es un valor entre -128 y 127 y ''10' asumiendo la conversión del compilador, claramente se sale del rango.

La solución es simplemente usar una variable entera para el `switch-case` en vez de `char`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
int opcion;
float num1,num2,num3,num4,perimetro,area,resultado;
float pi = atan(1)*4; 

int main (){
    do{
        std::cout<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------";
        std::cout<<"\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>Calculadora Suprema<<<<<<<<<<<<<";
        std::cout<<"\n  1.-Suma";
        std::cout<<"\n  2.-Resta";
        std::cout<<"\n  3.-Multiplicacion";
        std::cout<<"\n  4.-Division";
        std::cout<<"\n  5.-Area de un cuadrado";
        std::cout<<"\n  6.-Area de un triangulo";
        std::cout<<"\n  7.-Area de un circulo";
        std::cout<<"\n  8.-Area de un poligono regular";
        std::cout<<"\n  9.-Volumen de un prisma rectangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  10.-Volumen de un prisma triangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  11.-Volumen de un prisma poligonal";
        std::cout<<"\n  12.-Volumen de un cilindro";
        std::cout<<"\n  13.-Volumen de un cilindro truncado diagonal";
        std::cout<<"\n  14.-Volumen de una esfera";
        std::cout<<"\n  15.-Volumen de el segmento de una esfera";
        std::cout<<"\n  16.-Volumen de el casquete de una esfera";
        std::cout<<"\n  17.-Volumen de una piramide rectangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  18.-Volumen de una piramide triangular";
        std::cout<<"\n  19.-Volumen de una piramide poligonal";
        std::cout<<"\n  20.-Volumen de un cono";
        std::cout<<"\n  21.-Volumen de un cono truncado";
        std::cout<<"\n  22.-Salir";
        do{
            std::cout<<"\n Intruduzca su opcion (1-22):";
            fflush(stdin);
            std::cin>>opcion;
        } while(opcion < 1 || opcion > 22);
        switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una suma";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu primer sumando: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu segundo sumando: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=num1+num2;
            std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la suma es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 2:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una resta";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu minuendo: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu sustraendo: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=num1-num2;
            std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la resta es: "<<resultado;
            break;  

        case 3:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una multiplicacion";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu primer operando: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu segundo operando: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=num1*num2;
            std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la multiplicacion es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 4:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando una division";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu dividendo: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce tu divisor: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=num1/num2;
            std::cout<<"\n El resultado de la division es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 5:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un cuadrado";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la base: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Indroduce la altura: 2";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=num1*num1;
            std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 6:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un triangulo";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la base: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Indroduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=(num1*num2)/2;
            std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 7:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un circulo";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            resultado=pi*(num1*num1);
            std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 8:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el area de un poligono";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la cantidad de lados: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la medida de cada lado: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            perimetro=num1*num2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el apotema: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            resultado=(perimetro*num3)/2;
            std::cout<<"\n El area es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 9:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un prisma rectangular";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de largo: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            area=num1*num2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            resultado=num3*area;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 10:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un prisma triangular";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la base: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            area=(num1*num2)/2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura del prisma: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            resultado=num3*area;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 11:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un prisma poligonal";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la cantidad de lados: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide cada lado: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            perimetro=num1*num2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la apotema: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            area=(perimetro*num3)/2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num4;
            resultado=area*num4;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 12:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cilindro";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            area=pi*(num1*num1);
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=area*num2;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
            break;

        case 13:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cilindro diagonal";
            std::cout<<"\n Ingrese la altura mayor: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Ingresa la altura menor: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            std::cout<<" Ingresa el radio: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            num4=(num1+num2)/2;
            resultado=pi*(num3*num3)*num4;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 14:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una esfera";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            resultado=(4*pi*(num1*num1*num1))/3;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
            break;

        case 15:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen del segmento de una esfera";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio mayor: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio menor: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            resultado=(pi*num3*((3*(num1*num1))+(3*(num2*num2))+(num3*num3)))/6;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
            break;

        case 16:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen del casquete de una esfera";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            resultado=(pi*(num2*num2)*((3*num1)-num2))/3;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: \n"<<resultado;
            break;

        case 17:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una piramide rectangular";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de largo: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            area=num1*num2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la pirámide. ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            resultado=(num3*area)/3;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 18:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una piramide triangular";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide de ancho: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la base: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            area=(num1*num2)/2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura de la pirámide. ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            resultado=(num3*area)/3;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 19:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de una piramide poligonal";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la cantidad de lados: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce cuanto mide cada lado: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            perimetro=num1*num2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la apotema: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            area=(perimetro*num3)/2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num4;
            resultado=(area*num4)/3;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 20:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cono";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            num3=pi*(num1*num1);
            resultado=(num3*num2)/3;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        case 21:
            std::cout<<"\n >>>Estas calculando el volumen de un cono truncado";
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce la altura: ";
            std::cin>>num1;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio mayor: ";
            std::cin>>num2;
            std::cout<<"\n Introduce el radio menor: ";
            std::cin>>num3;
            resultado=pi*num1*((num2*num2)+(num3+num3)+num2+num3)/3;
            std::cout<<"\n El volumen es: "<<resultado;
            break;

        }
    } while (opcion != 22);
    return 0;
}
```